# How to hide sidebar only in woocommerce single-product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I need to hide the right sidebar in understrap theme https://understrap.com/, only in my single woocommerce product page (not in shop).
By removing the lines (50 - 58) in the woocommerce.php template:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'understrap_woocommerce_wrapper_end' ) ) {
    function understrap_woocommerce_wrapper_end() {
        echo '</main><!-- #main -->';
        get_template_part( 'global-templates/right-sidebar-check' );
        echo '</div><!-- .row -->';
        echo '</div><!-- Container end -->';
        echo '</div><!-- Wrapper end -->';
    }
}
```

the bar disappears in the other pages example: "shop" (and I don't want to).

Do you think a function is needed? Has anyone already addressed the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function remove_sidebar_single_product_page() {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        // for understrap theme
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'understrap_woocommerce_wrapper_end', 10 );
        // for default woocommerce structure
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
        // add wrapper end for single product
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'understrap_woocommerce_wrapper_end_for_single_product', 11 );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_sidebar_single_product_page' );

function understrap_woocommerce_wrapper_end_for_single_product(){
    echo '</main><!-- #main -->';
    echo '</div><!-- .row -->';
    echo '</div><!-- Container end -->';
    echo '</div><!-- Wrapper end -->';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @itzmekhokan Works fine!
But I have a problem, when I insert the code my footer wrapper on this page breaks (screen 1 : https://ibb.co/WxgqCsd) and becomes a container while it should be full widht. (screen 2 :https://ibb.co/G3KwYmn).
Has it ever happened to you?

Comment: @p.perona, actually I never used this theme. Anyways I figured it out and updated my code. Can you please replace it with your previous one.